# Random resource selection

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-resources

I want to select certain audio files when a user presses a button but i cant seem to find how i can change the R.raw. so that it will change in here.

I know there should be a easier sollution than creating 1000 if else with
R.raw.0,  R.raw.1 ,...

So in my example i have selected file "c.mp3"
but this must be eventualy change to 000 till 499.
So random (or selective)  say 050 => this shoud become R.raw.050

```
}

@Override
public void play() {

    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.c);
    mp.start();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you have your random number like this :

```
String rand = "050";
```

It is easy you need just to find the raw resource id  and pass it to your MediaPlayer.create method like that :

```
int rawResourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(rand, "raw", this.getPackageName());

final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, rawResourceId);
mp.start();
```

Suggestion :

- It's better to rename your resources files by prefixing them by a letter like f_000 , f_001, ...., f_050.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using:

```
context.getResources().getIdentifier("050", "raw", this.getPackageName());
```

and randomize the name ("050") using a Random object instance.